# Why Am I Getting a SystemStackError In This Code?

Tags: ruby, string, class, ruby-1.9

```
class X
  class << self
    def attr_string arg
      eval("def #{arg}; return #{arg.to_s}; end")
    end
  end
end
```

Is the code I am working with. I am trying to make it into a class macro, like attr_accessor. When I call

```
foo = 50
X.attr_string :foo
X.foo
```

I get a `SystemStackError`. Why is this?

Comment: what should `X.foo` return? In your case it should return `foo`

Answer (score 0):

```
class X
  def attr_string arg
    (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
      define_method arg do
        arg
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or little cleaner

```
class X
  def self.attr_string arg
    self.class.instance_eval do
      define_method(arg) { arg.to_s }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: X.foo returns 'foo' and not 50.

Comment: @Anil, In his code he returns not 50, but foo (if his code could work ;) )

Comment: I think he never got past the loop. To return foo, you don't have to call X. The fact that he assigned 50 to foo possibly means he was trying to get 50 back. Only He and he can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite recursion will do it.

Option 1(using class variable):

```
@@foo = 50

class X
  def X.attr_string arg
    eval("def X.#{arg.to_s}; return @@#{arg.to_s}; end")
  end
end
X.attr_string :foo
X.foo
```

Option 2(specifying the value while defining the method):

```
class X
  def X.attr_string arg, val
    eval("def X.#{arg.to_s}; #{val}; end")
  end
end
X.attr_string :foo, 50
X.foo
```

I guess `return foo` tries to run the foo method again, infinitely. But even if you named the variable foo1 and returned foo1, it will not find foo1 as a class variable as it has lost the scope.

You can try to wrap the value in a lambda or marshal the foo object. If you have luck with that, please post the results for all.

Interesting problem!

Comment: Still gives me the systemstackerr

Comment: I edited the answer and tested it. Is this closer to what you were trying?